# A betting game using a dice class in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, dice

This is my first project over 100 lines and I would like some feedback on it. If anyone has any ideas for things to add or ways to make the code more efficient they would be very much appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Betting game1 = new Betting();
        game1.rules();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        while (true)
        {
            game1.game();
            string answer = "";
            Console.WriteLine("");
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Would you like to play again?(y or n) ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!answer.ToLower().Equals("y") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("n"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid answer.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (answer.ToLower().Equals("y")) {
                game1.playAgain(answer);
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Betting
{
    private static long cashAmount;
    private static long player1Amount;
    private static long player2Amount;
    private static int rollAmount;
    private static long betAmountPlayer1;
    private static long betAmountPlayer2;
    private int numGames;


    public Betting()
    {
        cashAmount = 1500;
        player1Amount = cashAmount;
        player2Amount = cashAmount;
        rollAmount = 0;
        betAmountPlayer1 = 100;
        betAmountPlayer2 = 100;
        numGames = 0;
    }
    public void rules()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How the game works!");
        Console.WriteLine("First: You can either set the custom cash amount for each player, or leave it default at $1500.");
        Console.WriteLine("Second: Select how many dice you want to roll(5,10,15,20).");
        Console.WriteLine("Third: Ask each player how much they want to bet.");
        //Console.WriteLine("Fourth: The higher your bet, the better chance you have at winning"); not implemented yet
        Console.WriteLine("Lastly it will print the results, the new balance amounts, and ask if you want to play again.");
    }

    public void game()
    {

        Dice dice1 = new Dice();
        Dice dice2 = new Dice();
        string answer = "";

        while (numGames == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Would you like to leave the cash default(def) or set your own?(custom) ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!answer.ToLower().Equals("def") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("custom"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        if (answer.ToLower().Equals("custom"))
        {
            string newAmount = "";
            while (true)
            {
                long temp = 0;
                Console.Write("Please enter your custom amount: ");
                newAmount = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Int64.TryParse(newAmount, out temp))
                {
                    cashAmount = temp;
                    player1Amount = cashAmount;
                    player2Amount = cashAmount;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ENTER A NUBMER");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        // show amout to each player
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 amount: " + player1Amount);
        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 amount: " + player2Amount);

        // ask how many dice they want to roll
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("How many dice would you like to roll?(5,10,15,20) ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!answer.ToLower().Equals("5") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("10") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("15") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("20"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid amount.");
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;

        }

        // ask how much each player wants to bet
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Player 1 bet amount: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Int64.TryParse(answer, out betAmountPlayer1))
            {
                if (betAmountPlayer1 < 0 || betAmountPlayer1 > player1Amount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number.");
                    continue;
                }
                else if (betAmountPlayer1 <= player1Amount)
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid amount.");
                continue;
            }
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Player 2 bet amount: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Int64.TryParse(answer, out betAmountPlayer2))
            {
                if (betAmountPlayer2 < 0 || betAmountPlayer2 > player2Amount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number.");
                    continue;
                }
                else if (betAmountPlayer2 <= player2Amount)
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid amount.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        // roll the dice
        while (true)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(answer, out rollAmount))
            {
                //Dice dice1 = new Dice();
                //Dice dice2 = new Dice();
                dice1.rollDiceNoShow(rollAmount, true);
                dice2.rollDiceNoShow(rollAmount, false);
                break;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a vaild number");
            continue;
        }

        // print who had the higher sum
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 had a score of: " + dice1.getPlayer1Sum());
        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 had a score of: " + dice2.getPlayer2Sum());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        winner(dice1, dice2);

        // ask if they want to play again

    }

    public void winner(Dice dice1, Dice dice2)
    {
        // check for the winner and update the cash amounts and show's their new balance

        if(dice1.getPlayer1Sum() > dice2.getPlayer2Sum())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            player1Amount += betAmountPlayer2;
            player2Amount -= betAmountPlayer2;
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1's new balance: " + player1Amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2's new balance: " + player2Amount);

        }
        else if (dice1.getPlayer1Sum() == dice2.getPlayer2Sum())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a tie! no one wins!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1's balance: " + player1Amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2's balance: " + player2Amount);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            player2Amount +=  betAmountPlayer1;
            player1Amount -= betAmountPlayer1;
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1's new balance: " + player1Amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2's new balance: " + player2Amount);
        }

    }
    public void playAgain(string answer)
    {
        if (answer.ToLower().Equals("y"))
        {
            numGames++;
        }
    }
}

class Dice
{
    private int player1Sum;
    private int player2Sum;
    private static int sides;
    public Dice()
    {
        sides = 6;
        player1Sum = 0;
        player2Sum = 0;
    }

    public int rollDice(long nd) //nd = numDice
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (nd == 1)
        {
            int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
            return newSide;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= nd; i++)
        {

            int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Dice Number " + i + " has landed on " + newSide);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public void rollDiceNoShow(long nd, Boolean player1) //nd = numDice
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        // if there is only one dice
        if (player1)
        {
            int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
            player1Sum += newSide;
        }
        else
        {
            int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
            player2Sum += newSide;
        }

        // more than one dice
        if (player1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= nd; i++)
            {

                int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
                player1Sum += newSide;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= nd; i++)
            {

                int newSide = rand.Next(1, sides + 1);
                player2Sum += newSide;
            }
        }

    }

    public int getPlayer1Sum()
    {

        return player1Sum;
    }

    public int getPlayer2Sum()
    {
        return player2Sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, let's start by refactoring the `Dice` class:

```
public sealed class Die
{
    private readonly Func<int, int, int> randomNumberGenerator;

    public int MinimumValue { get; }
    public int NumberOfSides { get; }

    public Die(int minimumValue, int numberOfSides, Func<int, int, int> randomNumberGenerator) {
        this.randomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;

        this.MinimumValue = minimumValue;
        this.NumberOfSides = checked(numberOfSides + 1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Roll(int numberOfDice) {
        if (0 == numberOfDice) {
            yield break;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; (i < numberOfDice); i++) {
                yield return randomNumberGenerator(MinimumValue, NumberOfSides);
            }
        }
    }
    public int Roll() => Roll(1).Single();
    public long RollAndSum(int numberOfDice) => Roll(numberOfDice).Select(d => ((long)d)).Sum();
}
```

By saving a dedicated random number generator delegate during construction we can save the overhead of calling `new Random()` during repeated calls to `Roll`. In addition, the static member `sides` has been converted into an instance member because sharing that value amongst all `Dice` seemed like a very restrictive choice.

Altering the `Roll` method so that it returns a set of values gives us a bit of flexibility and allows us to get rid of the duplicate code that was in `rollDiceNoShow` (now called `RollAndSum`).

Now we need something to hold the metadata for our players:

```
public class BettingPlayer
{
    public long CurrentAmount { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Func<int, int, int> RandomNumberGenerator { get; }
    public long WagerAmount { get; }

    public BettingPlayer(long currentAmount, string name, Func<int, int, int> randomNumberGenerator, long wagerAmount) {
        this.CurrentAmount = currentAmount;
        this.Name = name;
        this.RandomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;
        this.WagerAmount = wagerAmount;
    }

    public BettingPlayer Lost(long newWager) => new BettingPlayer((CurrentAmount - WagerAmount), Name, RandomNumberGenerator, newWager);
    public BettingPlayer Lost() => Lost(WagerAmount);
    public BettingPlayer Won(long newWager) => new BettingPlayer((CurrentAmount + WagerAmount), Name, RandomNumberGenerator, newWager);
    public BettingPlayer Won() => Won(WagerAmount);
}
```

This allows us to shuttle state around and grants us the ability us assign each player their own (potentially biased) random number generator; can be used to assign a handicap or advantage to certain players. Finally, the game class itself:

```
public sealed class BettingGame
{
    private readonly int minimumValuePerDie;
    private readonly int numberOfDice;
    private readonly int numberOfSidesPerDie;

    private BettingPlayer[] players;

    public int NumberOfGamesPlayed { get; private set; }

    public BettingGame(int numberOfDice, int numberOfSidesPerDie, int minimumValuePerDie, params BettingPlayer[] players) {
        this.minimumValuePerDie = minimumValuePerDie;
        this.numberOfDice = numberOfDice;
        this.numberOfSidesPerDie = numberOfSidesPerDie;
        this.players = players;

        this.NumberOfGamesPlayed = 0;
    }

    public BettingPlayer GetWinner() => players.Aggregate((x, y) => (x.CurrentAmount > y.CurrentAmount) ? x : y);
    public void PlayRound() {
        var highScoreIds = new List<long>();
        var highScoreValue = 0L;
        var numberOfPlayers = players.Length;

        for (var i = 0; (i < numberOfPlayers); i++) {
            var currentPlayer = players[i];
            var score = new Die(minimumValuePerDie, numberOfSidesPerDie, currentPlayer.RandomNumberGenerator).RollAndSum(numberOfDice);

            if (score > highScoreValue) {
                highScoreIds.Clear();
                highScoreIds.Add(i);

                highScoreValue = score;
            }
            else if (score == highScoreValue) {
                highScoreIds.Add(i);
            }
        }

        var results = new BettingPlayer[numberOfPlayers];

        for (var i = 0; (i < highScoreIds.Count); i++) {
            var playerId = highScoreIds[i];

            results[playerId] = players[playerId].Won();
        }

        for (var i = 0; (i < results.Length); i++) {
            var temp = results[i];

            if (temp == null) {
                results[i] = players[i].Lost();
            }
        }

        players = results;

        NumberOfGamesPlayed++;
    }

    private static int GetIntegerInput(string message) {
        Console.Write($"{message}: ");

        while (true) {
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int numberOfPlayers)) {
                return numberOfPlayers;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int GetNumberOfPlayers() => GetIntegerInput("enter the number of players");
    public static long GetPlayerWager(int playerNumber) => GetIntegerInput($"enter the wager amount for player {playerNumber}");
    public static long GetPlayerStartingCash(int playerNumber) => GetIntegerInput($"enter the starting cash for player {playerNumber}");
    public static BettingGame Initalize(int numberOfDice, int numberOfSidesPerDie) {
        var minimumValuePerDie = 0;
        var numberOfPlayers = GetNumberOfPlayers();
        var players = new BettingPlayer[numberOfPlayers];

        for (var i = 0; (i < numberOfPlayers); i++) {
            var rng = new Random();

            players[i] = new BettingPlayer(GetPlayerStartingCash(i), $"Player {i}", rng.Next, GetPlayerWager(i));
        }

        return new BettingGame(numberOfDice, numberOfSidesPerDie, minimumValuePerDie, players);
    }
}
```

The BettingGame class encapsulates the state required to play; the core logic of the game has been separated from everything else in order to clean everything up a bit and an initialization step has been added to allow for a variable number of players/settings.

**Example Usage:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var game = BettingGame.Initalize(numberOfDice: 1, numberOfSidesPerDie: 1);

        game.PlayRound();

        var winner = game.GetWinner();

        Console.WriteLine($"the winner is: {winner.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"they ended the game with: {winner.CurrentAmount}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `GetWinner` doesn't handle the case where one or more players end the series a tie; I was too lazy to come up with something better
- there are bits of code that were intentionally left out (such as the `rules` method); again, out of laziness

Answer (score 3):

### Dealing with Console and User Input

You have lots of verbose, repeating code requesting user input.

> ```
> while (true)
> {
>     Console.Write("Would you like to play again?(y or n) ");
>     answer = Console.ReadLine();
>     if (!answer.ToLower().Equals("y") && !answer.ToLower().Equals("n"))
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid answer.");
>         Console.WriteLine("");
>         continue;
>     }
>     else
>         break;
> }
> ```

Wouldn't you rather write something like ..

```
if (PlayAgain())
{
   // perform logic ..
} 
else {
   // perform logic ..
}
```

You should seperate user input logic from the game and use a simple pattern for requesting user input.

Show a `message` to the user, with a list of `options` appended. The user output is tested against the options, unless no options are specified. Two functions `projection` and `layout` are provided to map the user output from `string` to `T` and vice versa.

## Pattern used for requesting user input

```
static T ReadInput<T>(
    string message, 
    Func<string, T> projection,
    Func<T, string> layout,
    params T[] options)
{
    var correctInput = false;
    var input = default(T);
    var formattedMessage = options == null || options.Length == 0
        ? message : $"{message} [{string.Join(", ", options.Select(layout))}]";

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(formattedMessage);

    do
    {
        Console.Write(">");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        var inputToken = Console.ReadLine();
        var error = false;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

        try
        {
            input = projection(inputToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            error = true;
        }

        correctInput = !error && (
               options == null 
            || options.Length == 0
            || options.Any(o => o.Equals(input))
        );

        if (!correctInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
        }

    } while (!correctInput);

    return input;
}
```

## Operations requesting for user input

```
public static bool PlayAgain()
{
    return ReadInput(
        "Would you like to play again?", 
         x => {
             switch (x.Trim().ToLowerInvariant())
             {
                 case "y":
                     return true;
                 case "n":
                     return false;
                 default:
                     throw new FormatException();
             }
         },
         x => x ? "y" : "n",
         true, false);
}

public enum CashOption
{
    Default,
    Custom
}

public static CashOption PickCashOption()
{
    return ReadInput(
        "Would you like to leave the cash default or set your own?",
         x => (CashOption)Enum.Parse(typeof(CashOption), x.Trim(), true),
         x => x.ToString(),
         Enum.GetValues(typeof(CashOption)).Cast<CashOption>().ToArray());
}

public static long PickAmount()
{
    return ReadInput(
        "Please enter your custom amount:",
         x => long.Parse(x),
         x => x.ToString());
}

public static int PickDiceRolls()
{
    return ReadInput(
        "How many dice would you like to roll?",
         x => int.Parse(x),
         x => x.ToString(),
         5, 10, 15, 20);
}
```

## Usage in your game

```
var cashOption = PickCashOption();
if (cashOption = CashOption.Default)
{
  // perform logic ..
}
```

Display

```
Would you like to leave the cash default or set your own? [Default, Custom]
>
```